# Duda JavaScript: desordenar array con bucle

Tags: javascript, java, array, script

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para un trabajo y tengo un problema a la hora de desordenar un array. Es decir, tengo un array llamado "numeros" y una función que lo desordena. Después creo un array vacío llamado "numerosDesordenados" el cual lo llenaré con tres posiciones, las cuales serán tres veces el array "numeros" desordenado de diferente manera. ¿Por qué cuando creo las posiciones del array "numerosDesordenados" con la función de desordenar el array "numeros" siempre me crea el mismo desorden? Os muestro código y el resultado:

```
function desordenar(array){
  array = array.sort(function() {return Math.random() - 0.5});
  return array;
} // esta función me desordena un array

var numeros= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //este es mi array

numerosDesordenados= []; // array vacio

for (i=0;i<3;i++){ //creo bucle para llenar array vacío
  numerosDesordenados[i] = desordenar(numeros);
}
```

Si hago un `console.log(numeros)` me muestra en consola `["1, "2", "3", "4", "5"]`. Bien...Si hago un `console.log(numerosDesordenados)` me muestra un array con tres posiciones siempre con la misma mezcla, por ejemplo:

```
[0] = ["2","3","1","5","4"]

[1] = ["2","3","1","5","4"]

[3] = ["2","3","1","5","4"]
```

Yo quiero que las tres posiciones sean diferentes. Como lo puedo hacer??
Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede por que los arrays en javascript son objetos y las variables son referencias a esos objetos, asi que al ir asignando de variable en variable es el mismo objeto el que se referencia/cambia.

Una forma de hacer una "copia" de un array en un objeto nuevo es con el operador de propagación ( spread syntax ) que "expande" el array y así los elementos entre corchetes arman un nuevo array: [...array]

```js
function desordenar(unArray){
  var t = unArray.sort(function(a,b) {return (Math.random()-0.5)});
  return [...t];
} // esta función me desordena un array

var numeros= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; //este es mi array

numerosDesordenados= []; // array vacio

for (i=0;i<3;i++){ //creo bucle para llenar array vacío
  x = desordenar(numeros);
  numerosDesordenados[i] = x;
  console.log(i,x);
}

console.log(numerosDesordenados);
```

nota: uso el `x` dentro del loop sólo para hacer un log junto al `i`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator

En la expresión `return [...t];` los "puntos suspensivos" es el `operador de propagación` que lo que hace es tomar los elementos de `t` y propagarlos, o desparramarlos separados con comas, como esto se produce dentro de los corchetes, el resultado es un nuevo array.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido de mucho! Aunque tengo una duda... el 
return [...t]; que se supone que es el "[...t]", es decir, los puntos suspensivos. Soy nueva en esto y voy algo perdida...